# Pushing and pulling to/from private docker registry is horribly slow

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-registry

I've been playing around a bit with using a private docker registry for centralizing our images. The problem being that pulling images from this registry is incredibly slow (under 1 MBps) in the context where i can scp between these same two machines at over 100 MBps.

Has anyone encountered this before and can share a solution or am i just not configuring the registry properly ?

Also i'm not using anything fancy for storage, just the local fs, and i'm currently not using tls, just testing with the registry unsecured for now.

Answer (score 2):

Are you pushing a large image with many layers? If so this might be caused by the compression library used internally by docker.

Every time you pushes an image to the `docker registry`, docker have to decompress the image layers to stores it's information, so it takes processing time (unlike `scp`)

Read [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/26959) for an open issue on changing compression library to make this faster.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'll look into this further. Also it's not pushing we have much of an issue with, it's pulling the image.